# Proximal kernel if and only if there exists $x$ of norm 1 such that $\Lambda x = \|\Lambda\|$, $X$ a Banach space, $\Lambda\in X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

I am working through the proof of the following proposition V.4.4.7 in Conway's functional analysis.

$\color{blue}{\text{If } X \text{ is a Banach space and } \Lambda \in X^*, \text{ then }\text{ker}(\Lambda) \text{ is proximal if and only if there is }x \in X, 
\|x\|=1,\text{ and }\Lambda x = \|\Lambda\|.}$

Now the beginning of the proof goes as follows:

$\implies$ Let $M := \text{ker}{\Lambda}$. Define $f: X/M \to \mathbb{F}$ via $f(x+M) = \Lambda x$, so clearly $f$ is a linear functional with $\|f\| = \|\Lambda\|$.  Since $\text{dim}(X/M)=1$, there is $x \in X$ with $\|x+M\| = 1$ and $f(x+M) = \|f\|$. Etc.

The rest of the forward direction from there is very straightforward, but I do not understand this last sentence.  It is basically saying that $\sup_{\|x\| = 1} f(x)$ is attained, but it is not obvious to me why a continuous linear map from technically "$\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$" would give us this attainment.

Similarly, in the backwards direction:

$\impliedby$  Let $x_0$ be the element such that the hypothesis holds.  If $x \in X$ with $\|x+M\| = \alpha$, then $\|\alpha^{-1} x+ M\| = 1$.  But it is also true that $\|x_0 + M\| = 1$ (I'm assuming the reason for this is the answer to my previous question). Then since $\text{dim}X/M = 1$, there is a $\beta \in \mathbb{F}$ with $|\beta|=1$ such that $\alpha^{-1} x+M = \beta(x_0 + M)$. Etc.

I once again am not sure why this last sentence is true. Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I'm not sure. Any help or hints to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of a proximal subspace?

Comment: A linear subspace $M \subset X$ is proximal if for every $x\in X$, there exists a $y\in M$ such that $\|x-y\| = \inf_{z\in M} \|x-z\|$. In other words, there exists a closest point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point, since $\dim(X/M)=1<\infty$, the unit sphere of $X/M$ is compact.  Thus taking a sequence $\{x_n+M\}$ in this sphere such that $f(x_n+M)\to\|f\|$, we have a subsequence with a limit point $x+M$, and by continuity one has $f(x+M)=\|f\|$.

For the second point, since $\dim(X/M)=1$, we have $X/M$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F$.  Let $g:X/M\to\mathbb F$ be such an isomorphism, and put $\beta=\frac{f(\alpha^{-1}x+M)}{f(x_0+M)}$.  Then since $f((\alpha^{-1}x+M)-\beta(x_0+M))=0$, we must have $(\alpha^{-1}x+M)-\beta(x_0+M)=0$.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for the accidental downvote. Thank you very much for the answer; I will make note there is a slight typo in the definition of $\beta$ for future visitors to this post.  $\beta = \frac{f(\alpha^{-1}x+ M)}{f(x_0+M)}$

Comment: ahh yes, thank for spotting that typo! I will edit my answer.

Comment: And no worries, I didn't even notice the downvote.

Comment: I actually have one more question, as I didn't notice this before.  It doesn't seem clear that $|\beta|= 1$, since there isn't a direct relationship between $f(\alpha^{-1}x + M)$ and $\|f\| = f(x_0+M)$.

Comment: Never mind, got it

Comment: Why do we have $dim(X/M)=1$? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming to this post for future reference, @cciirrcclllee received an answer to this question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938005/conways-functional-analysis-v-prop-4-7