# Conway's Functional Analysis V Prop. 4.7

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

Hi, for the proof of this proposition, why do we have $dim (X/M)=1$? In the forward direction, why does this imply there exists $x\in X$ such that $\| x+M\|=1$ and $f(x+M)= \|f\|$?

In the backwards direction, the reason why we get $\| x_0+M\|=1$, is it because that $dim (X/M)=1$ again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any nonzero linear functional $x^*$, the quotient space $\dim X/\ker x^*$ is one-dimensional. This is straightforward: fix $z\in X\setminus\ker x^*$ with $x^*(z)=1$. Then, for any $x\in X$, you have $x-x^*(x)z\in \ker x^*$. So $X/\ker x^*=\mathbb C\, z+\ker x^*$ is one-dimensional.

If you have a linear functional $f$ on a one-dimensional space $\mathbb C\,v$, then $f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)$, and $$\|f\|=\sup\{|\lambda f(v)|/\|\lambda v\|:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}=\frac{|f(v)|}{\|v\|}=|f(v/\|v\|)|.$$ Now write $v'=v/\|v\|$ and $f(v')=e^{i\theta}\,|f(v')|$. Then $$\|f\|=|f(v')|=e^{-i\theta}\,f(v')=f(e^{-i\theta}v')$$ and $\|e^{-i\theta}v'\|=1$.

In the converse, suppose that $\|x_0-m\|<1$ for some $m\in M$. Then
$$
\frac{|x^*(x_0-m)|}{\|x_0-m\|}=\frac{\|x^*\|}{\|x_0-m\|}>\|x^*\|,
$$
a contradiction. So $\|x_0+M\|=\|x_0\|=1$.